# For logic gates, simplify (A'BC') + (A'B'C) + (ABC)

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Here's the expression to simplify:

*(A'BC') + (A'B'C) + (ABC)*

Some answers I've seen have similar expressions but there's four sets of A's, B's, and C's so that changes the number of distributions and cancellations, [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275411/i-cant-simplify-this-a-b-c-a-bc-a-bc-ab-c-abc-boolean-expression-to-a?newreg=284085e0ce0247ba8a34ba0612de58ee) one and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012493/how-to-simplify-the-boolean-function-abc-abc-abc-abc).

Here's what I have:

*(A'BC') + (A'B'C) + (ABC)*

*A'BC' + C(A'B' + AB)*

I later used De Morgan's Law but I'm not sure if there's improvement:

*B(A+C)' + C[(A+B)' + AB]*

Comment: Before I start my answer, are you familiar with the terms "Karnaugh map" or "Sum of Product Form"?

Comment: Unless you can make use of something like an XOR, there is really no simplifying possible here. If you use a Karnaugh Map you will quickly see that.

Comment: I know sum of products, that I normally use with logic tables though @rhkoulen

Comment: If it's not simplifiable it may be a trick question, the question doesn't imply whether it is or isn't so if that's as far as I can go that's fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have been given to simplify is called a "Sum of Products Form" (named very creatively obviously).

These are quite often simplified using a Karnaugh Map, which allows you to represent all possibilities in a table and visually categorize outputs into blocks with common factors, allowing you to make a more slimmed down version of your expression. However, this method has it's limits, which you can see with this example.

Here is an empty Karnaugh Map in three variables:
$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \downarrow A \hspace{0.5cm}BC\rightarrow& 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$
The entries in the array indicate the result of $[col]$ AND $[row]$. So, for your example:
$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \downarrow A \hspace{0.5cm}BC\rightarrow& 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$
Consider the top-right example. When $A$ and $C$ are $0$ and $B$ is $1$, the result is $1$, which corresponds to the term $(A'BC')$ because when we plug in the values, this results in $(0' \cdot 1 \cdot 0') = (1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1) = 1$

Then, the goal of using this map is to draw rectangular regions (can wrap around edges) such that all internal entries are exclusively $1$. Now, it's clear that there's really no way to simplify this further with AND and OR, because there are no possible blocks we can make that only have $1$'s.

However, you can make use of the XOR gate.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate), $A \oplus B = (AB') + (A'B)$
This is relevant in our first two terms, where you can factor out $A'$. Observe:
$$(A'BC') + (A'B'C) + (ABC)=$$
$$A'\cdot ((BC')+(B'C)) + (ABC)=$$
$$A'(B \oplus C) + ABC$$

And I think that's significant simplification for the problem in question.
If you are only allowed to use AND and OR, I'm fairly certain you cannot simplify further.